# How do I access the nested keys in this nested javascript object?

Tags: javascript, object, nested

I have the following javascript object:

```
result = {
    "banking6dig":{
        "GM-B-001":{
            "releaseDate":"2/2/2012 14:44","noOfHex":"3","versInfo":"6 digit Banking"
        },
        "GM-B-002":{
            "releaseDate":"1/2/2012 14:46","noOfHex":"3","versInfo":"6 digit Banking with changes"
        }
    },
    "paynpark":[]
}
```

**Explanation:**

"banking6dig" and "paynpark" are applications
"banking6dig" has two subversions : "GM-B-001" and "GM-B-002"
"paynpark" has no subversions.

Additionally, each subversion has its own properties,viz, "releaseDate", "noOfHex", and "versInfo".

This object "result" is built after a php request, so it can have any number of apps and subversions; the format, however is ALWAYS the same.

I have tried this on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2JLtZ/1/

1. How do I find out the number of "subversions" in each "app"? (I get some 40 "subversions"!)
2. How do I add an app to the object "result", e.g., "electricity" with its properties reset?
3. How do I add a subversion to "paynpark", e.g. "fixedRate"?
4. How do I modify a subversions properties, for example change "releaseDate" of "GM-B-001" to "3/12/2012 14:46"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

```
var i=0;
for (var j in result['banking6dig']) i++;
alert('banking6dig has '+i+' subversions'):
```

2.

```
result.electricity={}
```

3.

```
paynpark.fixedRate={};
```

Thanks AlienWebguy for pointing this out.

4.

```
result['banking6dig']["GM-B-001"]["releaseDate"]="3/12/2012 14:46";
```

Comment: Arrays are objects in JS. You can add any property you want. `var foo = []; foo.foo = 'bar'; alert(foo.foo);`. All it means is `foo`'s prototype is Array instead of Object.

Comment: @AlienWebguy I stand corrected, didn't know that and just verified it. Thanks, editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = {"banking6dig":{"GM-B-001":{"releaseDate":"2/2/2012 14:44","noOfHex":"3","versInfo":"6 digit Banking"},"GM-B-002":{"releaseDate":"1/2/2012 14:46","noOfHex":"3","versInfo":"6 digit Banking with changes"}},"paynpark":[]};

var app = [],
    svn = {};

for (var _app in result) {
    if(result.hasOwnProperty(_app)){
        app.push(_app);
        svn[_app] = [];
        for (var _svn in result[_app]){
            if(result[_app].hasOwnProperty(_svn)){
                svn[_app].push(_svn);
            } 
        }
    }  
}

// How man apps?
alert(app.length);

// How many subversions?
alert(svn['banking6dig'].length);

// Add an app 'electricity'
result.electricity = {};

// Add subversion to paynpark
result.paynpark.fixedRate = {}

// Add electricity
result.electricity = {};
app.push('electricity');

// Modify subversion
result.banking6dig['GM-B-001'].releaseDate = '3/12/2012';

console.log(result);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/DpCTP/

Comment: wowwwwwwwww.... ill be using that, thanks so much, pls do reply if I do have further doubts...